# Stored Procedure loses connection

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, stored-procedures, ado.net

I have an ASP.NET MVC project in which the model is managed through .NET entities and it seems that some times it loses the connection, but this happens only on stored procedures.

I get the following error:

```
Execution of the command requires an open and available connection. The connection's current state is broken.
```

Why is this happening?

Code

```
public ObjectResult<Categories> GetCategoriesStructure() {
        return ObjectContext.getCategoriesStructure();
    }


var catss = GetCategoriesStructure().ToList();
```

this exception occurs when I am trying to assign the List to catss variable

Object Context Instantiation

```
public abstract class ObjectContextManager {
    /// <summary>
    /// Returns a reference to an ObjectContext instance.
    /// </summary>
    public abstract TObjectContext GetObjectContext<TObjectContext>()
        where TObjectContext : ObjectContext, new();
}

 public abstract class BaseDAO<TObjectContext, TEntity> : IBaseDAO<TObjectContext, TEntity>
    where TObjectContext : System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext, new()
    where TEntity : System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.EntityObject {

    private ObjectContextManager _objectContextManager;

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns the current ObjectContextManager instance. Encapsulated the 
    /// _objectContextManager field to show it as an association on the class diagram.
    /// </summary>
    private ObjectContextManager ObjectContextManager {
        get { return _objectContextManager; }
        set { _objectContextManager = value; }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns an ObjectContext object. 
    /// </summary>
    protected internal TObjectContext ObjectContext {
        get {
            if (ObjectContextManager == null)
                this.InstantiateObjectContextManager();

            return ObjectContextManager.GetObjectContext<TObjectContext>();
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Default constructor.
    /// </summary>
    public BaseDAO() { }

    /// <summary>
    /// Instantiates a new ObjectContextManager based on application configuration settings.
    /// </summary>
    private void InstantiateObjectContextManager() {
        /* Retrieve ObjectContextManager configuration settings: */
        Hashtable ocManagerConfiguration = ConfigurationManager.GetSection("ObjectContextManagement.ObjectContext") as Hashtable;
        if (ocManagerConfiguration != null && ocManagerConfiguration.ContainsKey("managerType")) {
            string managerTypeName = ocManagerConfiguration["managerType"] as string;
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(managerTypeName))
                throw new ConfigurationErrorsException("The managerType attribute is empty.");
            else
                managerTypeName = managerTypeName.Trim().ToLower();

            try {
                /* Try to create a type based on it's name: */
                Assembly frameworkAssembly = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(ObjectContextManager));
                Type managerType = frameworkAssembly.GetType(managerTypeName, true, true);

                /* Try to create a new instance of the specified ObjectContextManager type: */
                this.ObjectContextManager = Activator.CreateInstance(managerType) as ObjectContextManager;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                throw new ConfigurationErrorsException("The managerType specified in the configuration is not valid.", e);
            }
        } else
            throw new ConfigurationErrorsException("ObjectContext tag or its managerType attribute is missing in the configuration.");
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Persists all changes to the underlying datastore.
    /// </summary>
    public void SaveAllObjectChanges() {
        this.ObjectContext.SaveChanges();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Adds a new entity object to the context.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="newObject">A new object.</param>
    public virtual void Add(TEntity newObject) {
        this.ObjectContext.AddObject(newObject.GetType().Name, newObject);
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Deletes an entity object. 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="obsoleteObject">An obsolete object.</param>
    public virtual void Delete(TEntity obsoleteObject) {
        this.ObjectContext.DeleteObject(obsoleteObject);
    }

    public void Detach(TEntity obsoleteObject) {
        this.ObjectContext.Detach(obsoleteObject);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Updates the changed entity object to the context.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="newObject">A new object.</param>
    public virtual void Update(TEntity newObject) {
        ObjectContext.ApplyPropertyChanges(newObject.GetType().Name, newObject);
        ObjectContext.Refresh(RefreshMode.ClientWins, newObject);
    }

    public virtual TEntity LoadByKey(String propertyName, Object keyValue) {
        IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, object>> entityKeyValues =
           new KeyValuePair<string, object>[] {
       new KeyValuePair<string, object>(propertyName, keyValue) };

        // Create the  key for a specific SalesOrderHeader object. 
        EntityKey key = new EntityKey(this.ObjectContext.GetType().Name + "." + typeof(TEntity).Name, entityKeyValues);
        return (TEntity)this.ObjectContext.GetObjectByKey(key);
    }

    #region IBaseDAO<TObjectContext,TEntity> Members


    public bool validation(TEntity newObject) {
        return newObject.GetType().Name.ToString() == "Int32";
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Comment: Please tell me you are not trying to keep a single connection open for all your queries.

Comment: I forgot to mention the most important. It doesn't matter if it's mvc or web forms but it's matter if the project is developed with .net entities. So, I think I have answer your question. Thanks for reply by the way

Comment: Do you mean "managed through the Entity Framework"? Please provide sample code that produces that exception.

Comment: Can you post the code where you are instantiating your ObjectContext? Are you passing a custom connection string in or using the default one it puts in the app config?

Comment: I am using the default connection. In my initial post I added the ObjectContext Instantiation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without knowing how you are instantiating your `ObjectContext`, I'll throw something in the answer bucket here.

This is how I do my Entity Framework commands and connections (for small simple projects at least):

```
using (MyEntities context = new MyEntities())
{
    return context.getCategoriesStructure();
}
```

You can also optionally pass in a connection string when instantiating your context (if not, it will use the one in your app.config):

```
new MyEntities("...connection string...")
```

If this does not help your issue, please help us understand your code a little better by posting how you are creating your `ObjectContext`.  You could at least attempt to do it this way to see if it works; that will tell you whether it is an issue with your connection string or not.